# Column item_name not found in android

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

Does anyone have an answer?

Code in my database helper class:

```
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEM_DB);
}

public static final String ITEM_NAME = "item_name";
public static final String ITEM_STATUS = "item_status";
public static final String ITEM_DESCRIPTION = "item_description";
public static final String ITEM_CATEGORY = "item_category";
public static final String ITEM_ROW_ID = "row_id";
private static final String ITEM_TABLE = "table_of_items";

   public static final String CREATE_ITEM_DB = "CREATE TABLE "
          + ITEM_TABLE + "(" + ITEM_ROW_ID + 
         " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + ITEM_NAME
          + " TEXT NOT NULL," + ITEM_STATUS + " TEXT NOT NULL," + ITEM_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT," + ITEM_CATEGORY + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
          KEY_NAME + " TEXT);";
```

Now, in another class I call:

```
  public void list(){
myModel.open();
current_user = myModel.getCurUser();
Item [] items = (myModel.getLostItems(current_user));
if(items != null){
    myView.setItem(items);
}

myModel.close();
```

}

myModel is the my database class. It holds an instance to my database helper class and my sqlite database. Also, myModel.open() gets a writable database.

The error message is very clear: item_name is not a column.

But it sure looks like it is.

Edit: After playing around, I have decided it is NOT ABOUT THIS PARTICULAR COLUMN. It seems any column thaT I put first in the columns array results in the same error message.

Edit 2: Here is my getLostItems:

```
     public Item[] getLostItems(String current_user) {
    String [] columns = new String [] {DB_Helper.ITEM_NAME,
            DB_Helper.ITEM_STATUS,
            DB_Helper.ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
            DB_Helper.ITEM_CATEGORY,
            DB_Helper.ITEM_ROW_ID,
            DB_Helper.KEY_NAME};
    Cursor c = database.query(DB_Helper.DATABASE_TABLE_USERS, columns, DB_Helper.KEY_NAME + " = ? AND " + DB_Helper.ITEM_STATUS + " = ?",
             new String[] {current_user, "lost"},
             null,
             null,
             null);
```

Technically, there is a little bit more code, but after walking through the code with the debugger, it fails on the query statement.

Log:

```
03-02 16:44:56.375: E/SQLiteLog(16362): (1) no such column: item_name
03-02 16:44:56.375: D/AndroidRuntime(16362): Shutting down VM


03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wheresmystuff/com.example.wheresmystuff.View.DisplayItems}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: item_name (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT item_name, item_status, item_description, item_category, row_id, id_name FROM reg_users_table WHERE id_name = ? AND item_status = ?
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: item_name (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT item_name, item_status, item_description, item_category, row_id, id_name FROM reg_users_table WHERE id_name = ? AND item_status = ?
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at com.example.wheresmystuff.Model.DB.getLostItems(DB.java:180)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at com.example.wheresmystuff.Presenter.ListingPresenter.list(ListingPresenter.java:33)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at com.example.wheresmystuff.Presenter.ListingPresenter.<init>(ListingPresenter.java:26)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at com.example.wheresmystuff.View.DisplayItems.onCreate(DisplayItems.java:26)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-02 06:47:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6760):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Where do You get that error message?

Comment: Can you please paste myModel.getLostItems() method code?

Comment: what is the value of `ITEM_NAME`?

Comment: As It is showing error in select statement

Comment: @AkbariDipali Posted my query that causes application to fail.

Comment: @AnujMathur_07 it is just a string "item_name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra comma instead of

```
KEY_NAME + " TEXT,
```

It should be

```
KEY_NAME + " TEXT);"
```

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to be edited out. After correcting this, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Post your query statement. It seems you need a literal somewhere in your query.

Comment: Done. I posted the query. I still don't see why it doesn't work

Comment: Just hard code current_user value in your query and see if it works. So instead of new String[]{current_user, "lost"}, try new String[]{"John", "lost"} to see if it works. If it does, then there is something wrong with the String current_user. Also, even though it should not matter, change " = ? " to "=?"

Comment: Also, since you want every columns in your query, you can pass null instead of columns in the second parameter. Post the KEY_NAME definition.

Comment: You post code for ITEM_TABLE = "table_of_items", but in your query your first param is DATABASE_TABLE_USERS = "reg_users_table"

Answer (score 0):

Here, it is showing error message in select statement in myModel.getLostItems() method, please check whether you are passing correct parameters with '' for item_name column in your query.

Comment: yeah, I just posted my query statement. I don't even use item_name in my query statement.